# How can I return multiple values from a function that would support IDE autocompletion?

Tags: php, data-transfer-objects

Imagine that you have a function which selects data from a database table, using something like this query:

```
select count(id), sum(amount) from payments group by amount;
```

It then passes the results to another function, which loops through the results and returns an array, with each element in the array referring to one row from the result. For example:

```
private function packageResults(array $results)
{
    $ret = [];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        // add $result['sum'] and $result['count'] to something, then add it to the $ret array
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Now, if in the `foreach` loop, I add the results to an associative array or `StdClass` and then add it to `$ret`, you will have to read my code inside of the `foreach` to find out the structure (I.E. the properties set on the `StdClass`, or the keys set on the associative array). What I mean is, since both of these data types are free-form, meaning they don't have their keys/properties documented anywhere, the person using my code first has to dump the output to know what this function returns.

What can I use to tell the user (and their IDE) what the structure of the data I return is, so that they wouldn't have to dig through my code to find it? Are data transfer objects made for this stuff? I'm thinking of data transfer objects because they are classes with their own properties, and this can be used to know what exactly my function returns. However, I'm not sure if this is the right approach from a software design point of view.

Comment: *"What can I use to tell the user (and their IDE) what the structure of the data I return is, so that they wouldn't have to dig through my code to find it"* - Explain the data structure you're using. if you don't want them to dig through the code, you need documentation. Does this answer your question? Looks like you already have a solution.

Comment: I could write a PHPDoc with all the properties set on each StdClass I return, or the keys set in the associative array I return. However, the problem is that the PHPDoc might get outdated as the structure of the data changes. What I'm thinking is that when you have something rigid like a class with its own properties, your code documents itself. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Code is always the best documentation, it just looks like I slightly misinterpreted what you meant by *"wouldn't have to dig through my code to find it"*. If you want to tackle the problem of duplication(code+doc) from a different perspective, you can use code generation techniques to use a common source for both the generated code and doc.. or extract doc from the code.. or vice versa. Which of these is the best approach for a particular problem is entirely dependend on the actual problem.

Comment: Can you give me an example in an answer so that I'd make sure I'm understanding you correctly? Imagine you're filling in the `foreach`. Would you create objects with predefined properties? Create objects from annotations? Etc?

Comment: Do you have unit tests? You could extract the documentation from there. Not only could you show the keys(fields) but also sample values for each field.

Comment: I was looking for something like an object I could use to get the data across. Look at the accepted answer, near the end, where the poster is talking about DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to hint others (IDE too) about constructs your function returns, use `@var array $results` phpdoc annotation, f.e.

```
/** @var BlahBlah $someVar */
$someVar = new BlahBlah();
$someVar->... (IDE will show you available things with context help now).
```

To show type of objects in array that you fill with foreach do:

```
/** @var BlahBlah[] $someArray */
$someArray = array();

$someArray[1] = new BlahBlah(); // (IDE should help you with context help if you use it later
```

You can also call it where you need it:

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($someArray as $value) {
    /** @var BlahBlah $value */
    $x += $value->getSomeValue(); // (IDE will help you with context help).
}
```

As for your case, if you know it will be an array and user of your function will need specific values, you CAN and SHOULD use a new class (DTO, as you wish) for it (I've never been a fan of associative arrays anyway). If you fill the fields of the object properly, you can then hint the user what type you are returning (and those fields can be annotated too, like for example $price will be stdClass, $something will be SomethingElse etc.) and he won't need to look inside your function, since what you are returning him will work as sort of an interface for him.

Have in mind though that it's not strictly DTO pattern. DTOs are used for expensive communication between f.e. webservices. I use this term here only as a simplification of sorts. If you want to know more about DTO, you should scan google for information about it (there is vast amount wherever you go).

What you need here is an object being an interface for data of sorts, that will aggregate the values that you need to get from database, operate on and pass to frontend, so more or less it's a POPO that you need (Plain Old PHP Object, equivalent of Java's POJO).

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said, I'm returning an array of StdClass, or an array of associative arrays. That means I'm not using a class, and I can't say `BlahBlah[]` to note that I'm returning an array of `BlahBlah`s. I'm returning an StdClass or an associative array. I could change it to be something else, but my question is, what should it be?

Comment: You can use stdClass as any other type (so in my example just use `stdClass` instead of `BlahBlah`). You can also nest it however you want (for multidimensional arrays). But I think your problem is that you are not actually sure what you are returning (since it's either array or something else - you don't know that at the moment of writing code). You won't be able to hint other devs what this is without explicitly describing it in your phpdoc to read. IDE won't be of much help here I think.

Comment: Well, I know exactly what I am returning: I am returning an array, with each element including the sum, and the count, I have retrieved from the database. My question is, what should each element be, so that the user wouldn't have to `var_dump()` my return value to see what it contains? I've edited my question in an effort to make my question clearer. I think the issue is my English here :)

Comment: If you know it will be an array and user of your function will need specific values, you CAN and SHOULD use a new class (`DTO`, as you wish) for it (I've never been a fan of associative arrays anyway). If you fill the fields of the object properly, you can then hint the user what type you are returning (and those fields can be annotated too, like for example `$price` will be `stdClass`, `$something` will be `SomethingElse` etc.) and he won't need to look inside your function, since what you are returning him will work as sort of an interface for him.

Comment: Awesome! I finally feel like I've gotten my point across. Now, is there something like a design pattern that speaks about returning objects that do nothing but act as documentation for the return value? Just to make sure I'm getting my point across, the only reason these classes exist are to document what I am returning (in this case, sum and count) and by what names. The name of the property could be anything. As long as it includes the word `sum`, you know you can find the sum in there. I've read the data transfer object design pattern and they don't seem to be talking about my use case.

Comment: It's not their only point. That's actually their "sidepoint". Let's say you have two developers, frontend and backend. Frontend one need some data to show to the user. The data can be given in various forms, but it's best to give it to him in some consolidated form. That's where `DTO` comes in. You get data from database, you do various things on it, and when it's ready, you pass it to the frontend developer as `DTO`. He doesn't need to know that "buildingPrice" is actually consisted of "windowPrice", "doorPrice" and "travelToMoonPrice", he only needs final result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you edit your answer to this so I can accept it so you'd get the points for helping me out? Thanks again.